# Creating dynamic array of strings to be used in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, listbox

I have a datagrid that is variable in terms of the number of rows it has while my application is edited by the user. I need to create a listbox that will list the strings contained one column of the variable datagrid no matter the length.

I have had trouble doing this and need a simple way to convert the column contents to an array of strings. And then use that array to fill the listbox dynamically.

Anyone done this successfully recently?

Visual Studio 2010 C#

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using arrays instead of lists?

your only option is something like the below

```
string x[];
for(int I=0; I < rows.count; I++) {
    x.push(rows[I].column["ColumnA"].toString());
}
```

basically you declare an empty array and then increase it by 1 each time you need to using the Push method.

Comment: No I don't have a bias either way. I was just trying to mimic examples I had found online. I have only been working with C# for 2 weeks now and am trying to teach myself as I build a new application for my company. I will try this and see what it does. It is similar to something I was just trying.

Comment: Fair enough,  i'd recommend using lists where possible,  then after you've done your data manipulation if you need an array make your code be something like "string[] x = new string[];  x = mylist.toarray();"   Lists will give you a lot more power to do better data manipulation and are completely dynamic by nature.   to add to a list you call List.Add(object).

Comment: That is awesome advice, thanks for the knowledge. That will help me out a lot in the long run because this application needs all the efficiencies it can get.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array, use a list of strings:

```
public IEnumerable<Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid grid)
{
    var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
    if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
    foreach (var item in itemsSource)
    {
        var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow;
        if (null != row) yield return row;
    }
}

var rows= GetDataGridRows(grid); 

foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)  
{  
    DataRowView rv = (DataRowView)r.Item;
    foreach (DataGridColumn column in grid.Columns)
    {

    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I gave it a try and when I went to debug it flagged me with an error. It seems System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid does not contain a definition for Rows. Is there a using statement I could have left out that would cause this? I have tried multiple possible solutions and have received this error a number of times.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you running?

Comment: Sorry, I did not know you were using WPF. I have modified my answer.

Comment: No problem and thanks, let me give it a try and see what happens. I've been struggling on this all day.

Comment: Something isn't clicking with that attempt either, bumped my error count from 1 to 85...

Comment: Make sure you replace "grid" with the name of your DataGrid.

Comment: I remembered to do that, the issue was more with the Microsoft.Windows.Controls.

Comment: After typing Microsoft. the intellisense would not generate Windows in the drop down

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it works fine:

```
 DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("ph_NO");
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "sonu", 213123 });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "abhay", 123411});
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", 234123 });
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;            
       listBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("DataSource", dataGridView1,"DataSource"));
       listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: No sorry Sonu, for some reason it isn't liking this either